# Creating news feed like views in XCode for iOS Apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, feed

I'm new to iOS App development. I'm finding my way around xCode and Objective-C. I would like to know how I can build news feed like Facebook for my iOS App ? I want to have something like a Template that I iterate through and generate. I'm not asking for spoon feeding me, but I'm very interested to know if anyone can point me to a tutorial or give me some pointers to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use a `UITableView` since there is tabled data involved.

Just load the data from an `API` and parse it.  Then, refresh the table view to show the data that you just downloaded.  To add load more and refreshing capabilities, check out `SVPullToRefresh` or `UIRefreshControl`.

There's loads of topics about each of these terms online.